# Continuous executing beforeMount in Vue3

Tags: mysql, vue.js

Hello and Happy Holidays!

I have a little error in my Vue3 application. If I'm using a beforeMount without a child component, everything is working fine. The code is executing only one time, the page shows up. But, if I'm adding a child component to the parent, Everything starts to go wrong and the code runs indefinitely.

**Parent component**

```
    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
              <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl modal-dialog-centered modal-dialog-scrollable">
                <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header">
                    <h1 class="modal-title fs-5" id="exampleModalLabel">Previzualizare deviz</h1>
                    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-body">
                    <DevizView :clientArray = "clientData" :vehicleArray = "vehicleData"/>// Child Component
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

<script>
import axios from "@/axios";
import DevizView from "@/views/Test.vue";

export default {
  props: {
    id: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      vehicleData: [],
      clientData: []
    }
  },
  components: {
    DevizView
  },
  methods: {
    async GetVehicleDetails() {
      await axios.post('http://localhost:3000/vehicle/GetVehicleDetails', {id:this.id})
        .then((res)=>{
          this.vehicleData = res.data;
          // Parse the stringified JSON into an actual JSON object
          try {
            this.vehicleData.vehicleTask = JSON.parse(this.vehicleData.vehicleTask);
          } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error parsing vehicleTask JSON:', error);
          }
        }).catch(err=>console.log(err))
      return this.vehicleData
    },
    async GetCustomerDetails() {
      await axios.post('http://localhost:3000/customer/GetCustomerDetails', {id:this.vehicleData.clientId})
        .then((res)=>{
          this.clientData = res.data;
          // Parse the stringified JSON into an actual JSON object
        }).catch(err=>console.log(err))
      return this.clientData
    },
  },
  beforeMount(){
    this.GetVehicleDetails().then(() => {
    this.GetCustomerDetails();
  });
    
  }
};
```

**Child Component**

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-sm caption-top">
      <caption><strong>Client/Predator</strong></caption>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th class="table-secondary">Nume</th>
          <td colspan="3">{{ clientArray.clientName }}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th class="table-secondary">Telefon</th>
          <td>{{ clientArray.clientPhone }}</td>
          <th class="table-secondary">Email</th>
          <td>{{ clientArray.clientEmail }}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th class="table-secondary">Data de intrare:</th>
          <td>{{ vehicleArray.vehicleEnterDate }}</td>
          <th class="table-secondary">Data de iesire:</th>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
```

If I'm removing the dynamic variables ( Example: ***{{ clientArray.clientPhone }}***) from the child component, eveything is working fine.

Thank you for your time.

Edit #1
Google Chrome dev error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length') at line 184
```

Node console:

```
Executing (default): SELECT `id`, `clientId`, `vehiclePlate`, 

`vehicleVIN`, `vehicleMake`, `vehicleModel`, `vehicleYear`, `vehiclePower`, `vehicleGas`, `vehicleCapacity`, `vehicleOdometer`, `vehicleTask`, `vehicleEnterDate`, `vehicleEstExitDate`, `vehicleDocuments`, `vehicleStatus`, `modifiedBy`, `createdBy`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt` FROM `vehicles` AS `vehicles` WHERE `vehicles`.`id` = '2';
Executing (default): SELECT `id`, `clientId`, `vehiclePlate`, `vehicleVIN`, `vehicleMake`, `vehicleModel`, `vehicleYear`, `vehiclePower`, `vehicleGas`, `vehicleCapacity`, `vehicleOdometer`, `vehicleTask`, `vehicleEnterDate`, `vehicleEstExitDate`, `vehicleDocuments`, `vehicleStatus`, `modifiedBy`, `createdBy`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt` FROM `vehicles` AS `vehicles` WHERE `vehicles`.`id` = '2';
Executing (default): SELECT `id`, `clientType`, `clientName`, `clientId`, `clientPhone`, `clientEmail`, `clientReg`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt` FROM `clients` AS `clients` WHERE `clients`.`id` = '12';
Executing (default): SELECT `id`, `clientId`, `vehiclePlate`, `vehicleVIN`, `vehicleMake`, `vehicleModel`, `vehicleYear`, `vehiclePower`, `vehicleGas`, `vehicleCapacity`, `vehicleOdometer`, `vehicleTask`, `vehicleEnterDate`, `vehicleEstExitDate`, `vehicleDocuments`, `vehicleStatus`, `modifiedBy`, `createdBy`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt` FROM `vehicles` AS `vehicles` WHERE `vehicles`.`id` = '2';
Executing (default): SELECT `id`, `clientType`, `clientName`, `clientId`, `clientPhone`, `clientEmail`, `clientReg`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt` FROM `clients` AS `clients` WHERE `clients`.`id` = '12';
Executing (default): SELECT `id`, `clientId`, `vehiclePlate`, `vehicleVIN`, `vehicleMake`, `vehicleModel`, `vehicleYear`, `vehiclePower`, `vehicleGas`, `vehicleCapacity`, `vehicleOdometer`, `vehicleTask`, `vehicleEnterDate`, `vehicleEstExitDate`, `vehicleDocuments`, `vehicleStatus`, `modifiedBy`, `createdBy`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt` FROM `vehicles` AS `vehicles` WHERE `vehicles`.`id` = '2';
```

**Line 184**

```
<tbody v-if="vehicleData && vehicleData.vehicleTask.length">
                  <tr v-for="Task, index in vehicleData.vehicleTask" :key="Task.id">
                    <th scope="row" colspan="2">{{ index }}</th>
                    <td colspan="2">{{ Task.title }}</td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
```

Comment: you are doing this.vehicleData = res.data; and after that you are doing JSON.parse(this.vehicleData.vehicleTask) is that a nested stringified value? In the second you are not parsing the data -> this.clientData = res.data; Is res.data really an array? And line 84 can probably be v-if="vehicleData?.vehicleTask?.length"

Comment: @user3791775, this is how I stored vehicleTask in database. [link](https://imgur.com/e0VUutM)

After I managed to stop the script. None of the variables received data. Not only vehicleTask

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I forgot to declare variables as props in child component.

```
<script>
export default {
  props: {
    clientArray: [],
    vehicleArray: []
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).